# CodeCanyon POI Auto Map doesn't work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, point-of-interest, automap

I can’t get my purchased script to work, and I don’t know what to do.

On menu page "Célula" I need to display a map with locations exactly like this one: http://www.igrejabatistadobosque.com.br/mapa-de-localizacao/

What have I done so far:

- Bought the plugin at CodeCanyon
- Upload the files to the server
- Activate the plugin in wordpress admin panel
- Get the key at google places API
- Set the database info for connection
- Set the database field names / mapping
- Click “save” in every item from de POI Admin panel

And after all this it still doesn't work. The CSS files didn't load by itself. I had to manually add the file at my code. The js files looks the same.

When I manually add this script at the head of my code the map is shown but in the middle of the ocean and without the configuration I have made in the admin page:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&language=pt-BR"></script>
```

The parallax effect on the quote blocks stops when I add this line above.

Can someone help me? The support hasn't answered my questions.